# Match Everything Between Specific UL

Tags: php, html, regex

I am trying to match everything between this specific ul but I'm unable to get it to match anything. Any help would be appreciated.

### HTML

```
<ul class="pagination_tabs" style="position: absolute; right: 14px; top: 17px;">
    <li><a title="" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a title="" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a title="" href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a title="" href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a title="" href="#">5</a></li>
</ul>
```

### PHP

```
if (preg_match_all("#<ul class=\"pagination_tabs\".*?>(.*?)</ul>#", $id_html, $matches)) { 
    echo "Found Match";
}
else{
    echo "No Match Found";
}
```

Comment: Since you're wanting to parse existing html instead of PHP code, you should probably use client-side javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matching XML/HTML with Regexp is something that you DO NOT WANT TO DO. Believe me.

I suggest you try to use [SimpleXMLElement](https://www.php.net/SimpleXMLElement) or [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/DOMDocument)

```
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->load('myfile.html');
$ul = $dom->documentElement->getElementById('pagination');
```

Comment: If you aren't going to answer the question you should use a comment instead.

Comment: As a definitive answer, it's bullshit anyway. I can think of thousands of valid cases for extracting data from HTML with a regexp, out of performance considerations or just out of convenience (a single regexp that replaces 50 lines of nested searches is an easy choice). For this specific case it's understandable advise, but still not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

A quick guess: you have line breaks in the text. That means that you'll need a flag to make `.` match newline. Its the `s` flag.

```
"abc\ndef" =~ /abc.+def/  -> no match
"abc\ndef" =~ /abc.+def/s -> match
```

Take a look at [this comment in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php#111573).

But do consider not using regular expressions at all. Parsing HTML (or XML) should be done using parsers for those formats.

Answer (score 0):

The regex should look more like this

```
/<ul class='pagination_tabs'.'[^>]*<\/ul>/i`
```

Though, I would use jQuery for this.

```
if($('ul.pagination_tabs li').length > 0){ alert 'Exists'; )
```

Comment: Why on earth would you need jquery for that?

Comment: Easier syntax. Why use PHP to parse existing HTML?

Comment: I wasn't talking about PHP. I am talking about the native DOM API provided by the thing that drives jquery: JavaScript.

Comment: But [jQuery is the answer to everything](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/219504)! I even use it to make coffee in the morning, it's faster than a coffee machine and more standardized.